# How to render perfect copy of the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I have tried with Chrome and Puppter following:

1. Wait long enough for all images to be loaded (as I had my browser opened it was easy step)
2. Make a copy of the DOM tree with document.cloneNode(true)
3. Filter out javascript (as I want static view only)
4. Finally return copy with XMLSerializer with serializeToString as a string an save as .html file.

The browser viewport was set the same size as the one from which the copy was made. However rendered page isn't acceptable some images are visible below others, rendered view is not the same.

Any idea why this is happening? I thought I had a perfect DOM copy.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't embed CSS into the file, in which case they may fail to load if the remote server has CORS restriction (also causes the failure with the images). Either 1) save to MHTML or 2) manually embed all CSS and images e.g. via data URI.

Comment: Yes, it is true. I have attached some of the styles from css but not all of them. I used window.getComputedStyle. Besides there were a lot resource loading errors on the browser side. Completely invisible on nodejs side. Thanks for the tip.